# React-NextJS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'taste' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have this problem with NextJS, it keeps showing me this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'taste' of undefined`, sometimes it shows me the correct output but most of the time it throws this error.

This is my code, it's a page that shows the details of an avocado based in the id that it receives from the url:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar/Navbar";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const ProductItem = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [item, setItem] = useState({});
  const { avo } = router.query;

  useEffect(() => {
    window
      .fetch(`/api/avo/${avo}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setItem(data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log("error: ", error));
  }, []);

  const {
    attributes: { taste, description },
  } = item;

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Navbar />
      <h3 className="text-center">{item.name}</h3>
      <br />
      <p>
        <span>Price:</span> {item.price} USD
      </p>
      <p>
        <span>Taste:</span> {taste}
      </p>
      <br />
      <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductItem;
```

This is what my fake api returns:

```
{
  "name": "Maluma Hass Avocado",
  "id": "2zd33b8c",
  "sku": "NUR72KCM",
  "price": 1.15,
  "image": "/images/maluma.jpg",
  "attributes": {
    "description": "A relatively new cultivar, it was, the pretty boy baby, discovered in South Africa in the early 1990s by Mr. A.G. (Dries) Joubert. Maluma Babyy. It is a chance seedling of unknown parentage",
    "shape": "Oval",
    "hardiness": "1 °C",
    "taste": "Catchy, is an avocado"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is trying to read the property `item.attributes.taste`:

```
const {
  attributes: { taste, description },
} = item;
```

But `item` is declared as an empty object:

```
const [item, setItem] = useState({});
```

Which means `item.attributes` is `undefined`, hence the error.

The quickest fix is probably to just initialize `item` with an `attributes` property:

```
const [item, setItem] = useState({ attributes: {} });
```

Alternatively, you can update how you manage state to track the `attributes` or even the `taste` and `description` values more specifically.  That way the initialization is a little less complex and easier to follow.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly help, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that until the item gets fetched from the API, the state set for the item is just an empty object `{}`. Therefore you get this error when you are trying to destructure it.

You can maintain two other states for 'fetching' and 'error' that validates if the API call is complete and successful as follows :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar/Navbar";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const ProductItem = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [item, setItem] = useState({});
  const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const { avo } = router.query;

  useEffect(() => {
    window
      .fetch(`/api/avo/${avo}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setFetching(false);
        setItem(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setFetching(false);
        setError(true);
        console.log("error: ", error)
       }
   );
  }, []);

 if(fetching){
  return (<div>Fetching</div>);
 }
 
 if(error){
  return (<div>Error</div>);
 }
  const {
    attributes: { taste, description },
  } = item;


  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Navbar />
      <h3 className="text-center">{item.name}</h3>
      <br />
      <p>
        <span>Price:</span> {item.price} USD
      </p>
      <p>
        <span>Taste:</span> {taste}
      </p>
      <br />
      <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductItem;
```

Comment: also, the `fetching` flag should also be set to `false` on error

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, you're initializing taste as the following,

```
const {
    attributes: { taste, description },
} = item;
```

Therefore, to access it, you would need to do:

```
{attributes.taste}
```

This is because you are declaring `taste` as an element inside of the object `attributes`. Therefore, you would need to access attributes first in order to get to the `taste` element.

You will also need to do this to the description element mentioned shortly thereafter.